# Show articles on new page

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a way to not promote articles on to the front page and instead gather them under a main menu link?

Like main menu link -> myArticles and on click all articles written will be shown there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent displaying from front page

Edit the article content type: /admin/structure/types/manage/article

In the Publishing options deselect the "Promoted to front page" checkbox.

And create a Page using views modules with filtering you content type and add link in the main menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes that would be relatively easy. How I would do that:

Edit the main menu: yoursite.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu and add menu item named `My Articles` (linking to a view is what I would do but you can choose to link it to anything you want - or nothing)

Edit the `article` content type: yoursite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article

1. in `Publishing Options` *deselect* `Promoted to Front Page`
2. in `Menu Settings`:

   - check `Main Menu` under `Available Menus`
   - select `My Articles` (or whatever name you chose) in `Default parent item`

Then every time you create an article select `provide a menu link`. This will obviously work best for new sites where you don't have to go through and edit old articles to be in the menu.

Comment: The Main Menu forces me to use a certain *Path, can't leave it blank?!

Comment: ah yes should have mentioned that... I usually use: https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items other options are possible; like jQuery disable just that link but not as nice/easy - see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/how-do-you-create-links-with-a-null-or-in-drupal